# RecyclerView matrix spannable cells

Tags: android, gridview, view

**Problem:** Is there an option in `Android` to display time table like this:

[image]

I have multiple classrooms, and multiple classes. The view should be able to display large amount of data, like `recyclerView`. The red line represents current time. Also the view should be able to be selected with keyboard keys(arrows) and clickable in order to perform some action. The length of rectangle should be calculated dynamically depending on duration of the class. This view should be scrollable *UP*, *DOWN*, *LEFT*, *RIGHT* like **horizontal** in **vertical** **recyclerView**. This view should display classes for current time and few that were passed and few that will come with option to scroll through them.

The information about classes I have handled with Retrofit2 and Realm DB. And now the major problem is how to display data in this form. Can you help me with advises, libraries, solutions or something to solve this problem? I am a newbie and really don't know where to start.

Comment: This view is not suited for moile.So simply break it into relevant parts and display one by one.

Comment: In this app it is solved, i guess... [link](http://ankerapps.com/images/portfolio/slide2.jpg)

Comment: this need both vertical and horizontal .and displaying data is complex.I just want to give you simple solution.